# WidgetKit: How to make print statements appear in the console?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, widgetkit

I am trying to find out why my Widget does not reload.
I want to print `entries` array from inside `func getTimeline` to the console.
However the print statements **do not** appear in the console.

**How to make print statements appear in the console?**

Comment: Did you check with a Breakpoint that your statement gets hit?

Comment: Even when I add a print statement at the beginning of the `func getTimeline`, it does not appear in the console.

Comment: And it seems to ignore the breakpoints.

Comment: Please make sure you are not filtering anything in the console, in that case, you won't see anything that doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run the widget for that, instead of the main target.

In Xcode, on the top bar, click on the name of the project, then select your widget extension.

[image: Choice of the target in Xcode]

Your breakpoints will now work, and your print statements will now appear in the console.